# Error when using spatial query in arcgis silverlight api

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, arcgis-silverlight-api

I'm developing a webgis using ArcGIS Silverlight API 3.1 . I used [esri interactive SDK sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#SpatialQuery)  for spatial query in the webgis .The problem is when i draw a freehand polygon and the polygon intersect itself (fig1), the error "Query failed: Error code '400':unable to complete operation." raised (fig2) . How can i solve the problem ?

[image: fig1]
[image: fig2]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in Silverlight, the way to fix the geometry is to simplify it. Use [ITopologicalOperator5](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriGeometry/ITopologicalOperator5.htm), set the isknownsimple to false and then call simplify which will return a geometry with multiple parts - in this case 3 parts.

Comment: Thanks Michael but we can't use Arcobject in silverlight API

Comment: That's a bummer. Do you have try..catch blocks in silverlight?

Comment: The problem is that it can't solve query result.I don't have any result.

Comment: That's true. But if your API can't handle non-simple geometries the only solution is to try..catch and return an error message. Ideally your API could fix it and solve the query but it appears that's not possible because you can't access low-level objects.